# Proving identity of Markov chain.

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains

I am in a need of proving the following identity. Hope someone can help me. Let  $\{X_n, n\geqslant0\}$ be a homogeneous Markov Chain. Show that $$P(X_{n+1}=k_1,...,X_{n+m}=k_m \mid X_0=i_0,...,X_n=i)=P(X_1=k_1,...,X_m=k_m \mid X_0=i) $$I know I should use multiple conditioning and the Markov property in some way, but can't figure out how. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Markov property yields
\begin{align}
&\mathbb P(X_{n+1}=k_1,\ldots, X_{n+m}=k_m\mid X_0=i_0,\ldots,X_n=i)\\ =&  \mathbb P(X_{n+1}=k_1,\ldots, X_{n+m}=k_m\mid X_n=i).\end{align}
Time homogeneity yields
\begin{align}
&\mathbb P(X_{n+1}=k_1,\ldots, X_{n+m}=k_m\mid X_n=i)\\ =&
\mathbb P(X_1=k_1,\ldots, X_m=k_m\mid X_0=i).
\end{align}